# Menubar program - Set focus to 3rd party application

Tags: c#, windows, menubar

I've attempted to find the answer with google but I guess I'm not using the proper terminology.

What I'm creating is a simple windows application that consists of a menustrip. This program is suppose to find the focus of an existing application that would already be running and "attach" itself to the top.

It's an older windowed game and I'm trying to create a toolset for it.

Id like it to be persistent and follow if the game is moved as well. But one step at a time.

I guess my question is what is the correct terminology for what I'm trying to accomplish. Once I know that I'll go and do some homework

Comment: You can get the window position using GetWindowRect (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and check it periodically to see if the window moves and adjust your window as required. There are some reports of this API returning bad values on Vista though, not sure if it has been fixed in 7/8/X.

Comment: "focus" is the wrong word. Focus is the state where a window/control receives input from the user. The window that you're typing into will have focus. You want to find the *main window* of a given *process* and then position the window of your own process near it.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

You can follow window using [uiacomwrapper](http://uiacomwrapper.codeplex.com/), I even have sample application on [github](https://github.com/FloatInCodeBlog/UIAutomationFollowWindowExample). On button click application will attach to IE and move together.

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string lpszParentClass = "IEFrame";
        IntPtr ParenthWnd = new IntPtr(0);
        ParenthWnd = FindWindow(lpszParentClass, null);
        if (!ParenthWnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            var parent = AutomationElement.FromHandle(ParenthWnd);
            Automation.AddAutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler(parent, TreeScope.Element, WindowMoved, AutomationElement.BoundingRectangleProperty);
        }
    }

    private void WindowMoved(object sender, AutomationPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            if (e.NewValue != null)
            {
                var newPosition = (Rect)e.NewValue;
                this.Left = newPosition.Left;
                this.Top = newPosition.Top;
            }
        }));
    }
```